# apache2 config - variable not evaluated in string

Tags: apache2

I want different routes to have their own password. So I have a `LocationMatch`:

```
<LocationMatch /shiny/(?<appname>.*)>
       AuthType Basic
       AuthName "Enter your login name and password"
       AuthUserFile "/path/to/directory/with/passwords/.%{env:MATCH_APPNAME}.pwd"
       Require valid-user
</LocationMatch>
```

But I am getting 500 Internal Server Error, because `%{env:MATCH_APPNAME}` is not evaluated:

`[Thu Sep 20 12:11:21.678370 2018] [authn_file:error] [pid 16932:tid 140332725917440] (2)No such file or directory: [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:52274] AH01620: Could not open password file: /path/to/directory/with/passwords/.%{env:MATCH_APPNAME}.pwd`

I am following the official instructions [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#locationmatch). What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

apache2 version: `apache2 (OpenRC) 0.34.11 (Gentoo Linux)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As referenced in the docs you quoted, Apache supports this style of regex references in **expressions** ([docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html)), but [AuthUserFile](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authn_file.html#authuserfile) expects a **file-path** as an argument - thus taking your string literally.

See the [If](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if) directive's docs to see how a directive supporting an expression is listed. The documentation page about expressions has a list of directives supporting them.